# Element Only Expanding 100% Of Viewport, Not Parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a 2 column responsive theme for SMF forum software. I wanted to stick a column on the right that would expand 100% the height of it's parent.

My problem now is my floated sidebar expands only to the height of the viewport, not parent element. I there a way to make this happen?

I have 100% html,body height, parent height, and sidebar height. However, it expands only as far as the viewport, not parent element.

Live Example:
http://xarcms.com/index.php?theme=3

Comment: What do you mean by the "floated sidebar expands only to the height of the viewport, not parent element"? The parent element is the wrapper which is set to height: 100%. So the viewport and parent element are the same? If I remove the padding on the sidebar (so, padding: 0 for the #side-section), I can float it left or right and the page looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution:

```
html{
    min-height: 100%; //insted of height
}

#wrapper{
    position: relative;
}

#side-section{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Sure, why not? Even `left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;` is ok.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Still, the element only expands the height of the viewport, not the parent element.

Comment: Actually, it does works once I removed "height: 100%" from all elements involved. However, I dunno if this is a complete solution. There will be a php option to float the sidebar to the right or left. Your solution solves my problem of it not expanding 100% of parent, but will cause the removal of the option to float the sidebar to the left or right. I will need to think about this, to see if I can come up with an alternative solution for how to set the placement of the sidebar using absolute position, if possible. PHP, isn't my strong suit.

Comment: Let's wait and see if there is another solution(better). If not, I will accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: Edited the answer a bit. Sure no prob. (about waiting)

Comment: This solution cannot be used by any circumstance. If a user remodels the theme and adds margin to the wrapper, then without "position:relative" the sidebar will jump outside the wrapper. I cannot add "position: relative" to the wrapper because I may need widgets that sit in the sidebar/header/footer to jump outside the wrapper. Any other ideas besides using a 2 column table?